# The background moves and pulls the content along with it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an adaptive, but as soon as I started to reduce the width, I saw that everything had shifted very much.
The question is why the photo shifts instead of shrinking while dragging the content along with it

CSS

```
//Styles for background
.header{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 900px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;

}

//Styles for the search menu

.search {
    width: 700px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    /* If you also want it vertically aligned to the center, uncomment the below lines and remove the above transform */
    top: 40%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    
  }
  
  .search_bar {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: antiquewhite;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: rgb(58 58 58 / 0.38);
    width: 100%;
    outline:none;
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wPqk.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C0PL.png)

I hope for your help friends

Comment: .header{
    position: relative; maybe it's because of using relative in header

Comment: Include a working snippet with HTML markup for people to assist you. The fast-dirty way is to use `overflow-x : hidden;` on `body`. With the info you provided, I see a `width: 700px;` on `.search` so that's where I would check. Replace that with e.g. `100%`.